# Return which optional pattern was matched

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm wondering how can i obtain which pattern in regex was matched.

I have this regex (i'm using .match in Ruby):

```
(?i)(penalty is\W+[0-9]+\W+night)|(penalty of\W+[0-9]+\W+)
```

Now i know how to return matched text in string, but is there a way to get matched string and matched pattern for that string ? So i will have two results:

1. Matched text in string: penalty is 1 night
2. Pattern that matched: (penalty is\W+[0-9]+\W+night)

Best regards.

Comment: Just see which group was matched.

Comment: If is group 1 it is `(penalty is\W+[0-9]+\W+night)`, if it is group 2 it is `(penalty of\W+[0-9]+\W+)`.

Comment: Ok, i understand, my fault :) you're reight it's working, thank you for help

Comment: @DawidPR Are you using `puts "...".match(/.../)`? This will convert the `MatchData` object to a string, so you cannot see the groups. If you use `p "...".match(/.../)`, or equivalently `puts "...".match(/.../).inspect`, then you'll see the full object.

Comment: Your pattern suggests that you are not interested in whether pattern #2 matches if pattern #1 matches. Correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pattern = /(?i)(penalty is\W+[0-9]+\W+night)|(penalty of\W+[0-9]+\W+)/

"penalty of 123 points".match(pattern)
=> #<MatchData "penalty of 123 " 1:nil 2:"penalty of 123 ">
```

The non-nil capture number reveals which part of the pattern matched. There are various ways that you could fetch this value, such as:

```
"penalty of 123 points".match(pattern).captures
=> [nil, "penalty of 123 "]

# Get the index of the first *non-nil* element:
"penalty of 123 points".match(pattern).captures.find_index(&:itself)
=> 1
```

So you'll know whether the first or second group matched, based on whether the method chain above returns `0` or `1`.

If you'd like to make this code a little more transparent (easier to understand how it works), you could also consider using a *named* capture group such as:

```
pattern = /(?i)(?<night>penalty is\W+[0-9]+\W+night)|(?<other>penalty of\W+[0-9]+\W+)/

"penalty of 123 points".match(pattern)
=> #<MatchData "penalty of 123 " night:nil other:"penalty of 123 ">

"penalty of 123 points".match(pattern).named_captures
=> {"night"=>nil, "other"=>"penalty of 123 "}

"penalty of 123 points".match(pattern).named_captures.compact.keys.first
=> "other"
```

To take this one step further, you could also define each "sub-pattern" as a distinct regex for future reference and join them together for the main match, e.g.:

```
groups = {
  "night" => /(?<night>penalty is\W+[0-9]+\W+night)/i,
  "other" => /(?<other>penalty of\W+[0-9]+\W+)/i
]

pattern = Regexp.union(groups)

match_group_name = "penalty of 123 points".match(pattern).named_captures.compact.keys.first

puts "Pattern that matched: #{groups[match_group_name]}"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
REGEXPS = [
  /(?<first>penalty is\W+[0-9]+\W+night)/i,
  /(?<second>penalty of\W+[0-9]+\W+)/i
].freeze

Regexp.union(REGEXPS) =~ ""
$~.named_captures
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's allow any number of unioned regular expressions and design the method to facilitate testing.

Let `str` be the string and `regexes` be an array of the regular expressions. For the example given in the question,

```
regexes = [/(?i)(?<night>penalty is\W+[0-9]+\W+night)/,
           /(?i)(?<other>penalty of\W+[0-9]+\W+)/]

def doit(str, regexes)
  regexes.each do |r|
    m = str[r]
    return [r, m] unless m.nil?
  end
  nil
end
```